# How to fix 'remove html content from formater in PDF export' jq Grid issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have jq Grid table with export options.
Created a custom button to Export to PDF inside of JQGrid, here is a bit of the code:

**JQ-grid code :**

```
 $("#list1").jqGrid({  datatype: "xml", colModel:[{name:'success',index:'SCOUNT', width:90,sortable:true,formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    if(cellvalue!=0)
                         var html ='<span sugar="sugar0b" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="showSuccessDetails('+options.rowId+');return false;"><u>'+cellvalue+'</u></span>';
                        else
                         var html ='<span sugar="sugar0b" style="cursor:pointer;">'+cellvalue+'</span>';
                         return html

                        }},
                {name:'failure',index:'FCOUNT', width:90,sortable:true,formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    if(cellvalue!=0)
                     var html ='<span sugar="sugar0b" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="showFailureDetails('+options.rowId+');return false;"><u>'+cellvalue+'</u></span>';
                    else
                     var html ='<span sugar="sugar0b" style="cursor:pointer;">'+cellvalue+'</span>';
                     return html

                    }}]
```

**Export Button Code:**
`

```
$("#exportPDF").click(function(){
                $("#list1").jqGrid("exportToPdf",{
                    /* title: 'jqGrid Export to PDF', */
                    orientation: 'portrait',
                    pageSize: 'A4',
                    customSettings: null,
                    download: 'download',
                    includeLabels : true,
                    includeGroupHeader : true,
                    includeFooter: true,
                    fileName : "CDR_Report.pdf"
                })
            });
```

The problem is on click of Export button it will export table as PDF in that for `Success column` and `Failure column` showing formatter html code also.
How to remove Html code for exporting only Needed `cellValue` in pdf.

Kindly check sample Image: Link[image]

Comment: Please, contact Guriddo support on how to do this.

Comment: @Tony: Can use `cellattr:function ` to replace `formatter:function` ? Using jqGrid JS - v5.3.2  and Jquery : v3.3